# How to disable monthly archive

Tags: archives

Is there a way to disable archives pages, specifically monthly archives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this post](http://betterwp.net/wordpress-tips/disable-some-wordpress-pages/) by BetterWP. You may need to edit the code as it does not mention about monthly archives.

Answer (score 2):

Another option I found, perhaps better is Yoast SEO plugin

[image]

Comment: For anyone wondering, this setting is located in SEO → Titles & Metas, where you’ll find the those options on the "Other" tab.